# How can I print text between 2 patterns AFTER matching on another pattern first?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

Imagine a line that looks like the following:

```
Some text with MATCH1_TEXT some other text and MATCH2_TEXT until MATCH3_TEXT
```

I want to ONLY search in lines that have `MATCH1_TEXT`, AND find the text *between* `MATCH2_TEXT` and `MATCH3_TEXT`.

In the above example, I would want to get `until` (with the space characters before and after the *until*).

Comment: Shouldn’t change the outcome, but curious to see how this could be accomplished using `awk` as well.

Comment: We need more example input and output. In particular lines with more than one copy of MATCH2_TEXT and/or MATCH3_TEXT. Clarification if the search can extend over more than one line, so MATCH2_TEXT and MATCH3_TEXT can be on different lines or not. If they can then does there have to be MATCH1_TEXT on the line with MATCH3_TEXT? Does MATCH1_TEXT have to precede MATCH2_TEXT pr can the line be `abc MATCH2_TEXT def MATCH1_TEXT ghi MATCH3_TEXT` and output ` def MATCH1_TEXT ghi `?

Comment: ... ↑ this clarification ↑ ...

Comment: I am looking for a pattern in a log file, searching line by line, not extending over multiple lines.  `MATCH1_TEXT`, `MATCH2_TEXT` and `MATCH3_TEXT` appear ONLY once in that line.  `MATCH2_TEXT` MUST precede `MATCH3_TEXT`, since the text I am looking for appears BETWEEN them.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about multiple lines and the fact that the patterns appear only once. Can you clarify the relative position of MATCH1_TEXT and MATCH2_TEXT, is if always the case that MATCH1_TEXT appears before MATCH2_TEXT on the line, always after, or might appear both before and after?

Answer (score 5):

For example with sed

```
sed -n 's/^.*MATCH1_TEXT.*MATCH2_TEXT\(.*\)MATCH3_TEXT.*$/\1/p'
```

assuming that the matching texts only occur at most once in a line and in order.

If `MATCH1_TEXT` could appear anywhere in the line then another way to look at the problem is to ignore any lines which don't have it, so the program then becomes

```
sed -n '/MATCH1_TEXT/!d;s/.*MATCH2_TEXT\(.*\)MATCH3_TEXT.*$/\1/p'
```

If the `MATCH2_TEXT` can occur more than once, e.g. the input was

```
 text MATCH1_TEXT stuff MATCH2_TEXT and MATCH2_TEXT until MATCH3_TEXT
```

then the question is what output is desired, `until` or `and MATCH2_TEXT until`? A similar question applies with repeated copies of MATCH3_TEXT. These can be handled with slightly more complicated sed programs. For example to keep the longest string

```
sed -n '/MATCH1_TEXT/!d;/MATCH2_TEXT.*MATCH3_TEXT/!d;s/MATCH2_TEXT/\n/;s/^.*\n\(.*\)MATCH3_TEXT.*$/\1/p'
```

which works by first rejecting any lines which are not suitable, then changing the first occurrence of MATCH2_TEXT to a newline (there will never be a newline in the line) then selecting the text between the newline and MATCH3_TEXT.

Some languages, such as `perl` and `python` have extended the operations available in regular expressions to allow "minimal match", which could help in these cases but are not needed. `sed` with its ability to loop conditionally is strictly more powerful than regular expressions.

Comment: The first paragraph (above) is what I would have said.  Good job on providing multiple answers for this under-specified question.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever we see the word "extract", the 1st thought to go out should be, can grep help here.

Here we first grep out the relevant lines and then feed those to another grep that then extracts the text found between match2 and match3 texts. This will even extract multiple match2/3 in a line.

```
$ grep MATCH1_TEXT file |\
  grep -oP '(?<=MATCH2_TEXT).*?(?=MATCH3_TEXT)'
```

Comment: I’ll give this a +1 for being, IMHO, somewhat unorthodox. But (2) If you have `|` (or `&&` or `||`) at the end of a command line, you don’t need ``\`` after it. (3) This works if MATCH2_TEXT is a simple string or even a fixed-length regular expression. But I don’t see anything in the (poorly worded) question that specifies that, and this answer fails if MATCH2_TEXT is a variable-length regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough example data to be sure of your actual requirements, but assuming your example is sufficiently canonical, so that

1. `MATCH1_TEXT`, `MATCH2_TEXT`, and `MATCH3_TEXT` are all on a single line
2. `MATCH1_TEXT` always precedes `MATCH2_TEXT`
3. `MATCHn_TEXT` may match inside `THEMATCHn_TEXTS`

you can then use a single invocation of either `perl` or GNU `grep` to extract the required data

```
grep -oP 'MATCH1_TEXT.*?MATCH2_TEXT\K.*?(?=MATCH3_TEXT)'
```

With your line of example data the output is `until` (with one leading and trailing space).

Comment: Again we see the lack of detail in the original question leading to different interpretations in the answers. I don't see anything that warrants putting in the `\b` in  the pattern and if you are going to put them in, why only on MATCH[12]_TEXT and not MATCH3_TEXT? The OP has clarified that they do want the whitespace included, so the second answer is not needed.

Comment: I agree with @icarus; I don’t see anything in either (1st or 2nd) version of the question that necessitates the use of ``\b``.  I interpret the edit as meaning only “don’t strip leading and trailing spaces off the text between `MATCH2_TEXT` and `MATCH3_TEXT`” — i.e., that the OP doesn’t want your second solution (with the `\s*`) — but nothing requiring `\b`.

Comment: There you go. `\b` removed and another assumption added